# How to evaluate Spring EL in Spring EL

Tags: spring, spring-el

(Sorry if this is a duplicate, but the question is very search-engine-unfriendly.)

I want to know how to evaluate Spring EL inside EL (with all the functions, variables, context, etc. passed through).

Specifically, I want to dynamically evaluate a Spring Security expression (which is just EL plus some functions and contexts) loaded from a database entity inside a hard-coded EL in `@PreAuthorize`.

I.e. something like `@PreAuthorize("eval(argument.securityExpr)")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend Springs MethodSecurityExpressionRoot (and create it in your own MethodSecurityExpressionHandler) and add an eval method which excepts a String and let the SpringExpressionParser evaluate the String. Should work...

Edit:

A little code:

```
public class MySpringSecurityRoot extends MethodSecurityExpressionRoot {
  private MyMethodSecurityExpressionHandler handler; // to be injected in the handler

  public boolean eval(String expression) {
    Expression expression = handler.getExpressionParser().parseExpression(expression);
    return ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(
       handler.getExpressionParser().parseExpression(expression), 
         handler.createEvaluationContext(authentification, methodInvocation));
  }
}
```

your handler must be set as the default method security expression handler:

```
  <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <security:expression-handler ref="myHandler"/>
  </security:global-method-security>
```

now your eval function is accessible in every method security expression

BUT: You must be aware of the fact that the person who describes your security rule, can access all beans inside the current spring context! Might be a security leak.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a simpleparametername discover with `@` to evaluate permissions you can do virtually anything you want, without enabling debug mode.

```
@PreAuthorize("@mySecurityService.hasPermission(#arg0)")
public String getSpecial(final String special) {
        return "authorized";
}
```

mySecurityService can be any bean/method returning a boolean, with this wired up for arg1

```
 public class SimpleParameterNameDiscoverer implements ParameterNameDiscoverer {

        public String[] getParameterNames(Method m) {
            return getParameterNames(m.getParameterTypes().length);
        }

        public String[] getParameterNames(Constructor c) {
            return getParameterNames(c.getParameterTypes().length);
        }

        protected String[] getParameterNames(int length) {
            String[] names = new String[length];

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                names[i] = "arg" + i;

            return names;
        }


    }
```

and context :

```
<bean id="methodSecurityExpressionHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
        <property name="parameterNameDiscoverer">
            <bean class="your.path.SimpleParameterNameDiscoverer"/>
        </property>
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your answer correctly, but it seems to focus on how to get the argument as opposed to how to evaluate the security expression stored in the argument. I already have access to the argument, but I don't know how to evaluate the security expression (i.e. your `@mySecurityService.hasPermission()` bit).

Comment: The thing is I rely on Spring to evaluate the expression. I don't have a method in my project to do it.

Comment: well then the other answer won't help either, you have to create your own handler. This is how you can create special handler ... but the other answer is good too, probably simpler.  http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/expression-based-authorization

Comment: Yes, but I think it points me in the right direction. It's relatively easy to sub-class the `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` to add a function than having to write the whole evaluation logic.